# is anyone know 502 bad gateway error solution in beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, docker, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
"above is docker file"
"below is travis-ci code"
language: generic
sudo: required
services:
- docker

## Build testing container

before_install:
- docker build -t brijesh -f Dockerfile.dev  .

## Run Tests

script:
- docker run -e CI=true -p 80:3000  brijesh:latest npm run test -- --coverage

deploy:
provider: elasticbeanstalk
region: "ap-south-1"
app: "docker"
env: "Docker-env"
bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-532163291253"
bucket_path: "docker"
on:
branch: master
access_key_id: $access_key
secret_access_key: $secret_key

[image]

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"] "docker file"

Comment: language: generic
sudo: required
services:
    - docker

# Build testing container
before_install:
    - docker build -t brijesh -f Dockerfile.dev  .

# Run Tests
script:
        - docker run -e CI=true -p 80:3000  brijesh:latest npm run test -- --coverage

deploy:
    provider: elasticbeanstalk
    region: "ap-south-1"
    app: "docker"
    env: "Docker-env"
    bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-532163291253"
    bucket_path: "docker"
    on:
      branch: master
    access_key_id: $access_key
    secret_access_key: $secret_key "travis code"